# VBA Cycle excel table columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table in which the first field is an ID. I would like to cycle through the first column checking if the id's match.

The question is how to achieve this since i don't know the end range.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you might want to use Find and FindNext

```
'Here you might want to deduce the range using .End(xlUp).Row with
'65,535 in 2003- or about 1,000,000 as a starting point in 2007+
With Worksheets(4).Range("A:A")
    Set rng = .Find What:="what you're looking for"
    While Not rng Is Nothing
        'do something
        Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
    Wend
End With
```

(Not tested but it shouldn't be to hard to make it work)

Comment: Very elegant solution.  This method will also be very quick because you are using built in compiled Excel functions (.Find) rather than iterating through loops and comparing which would be slower.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research i found the answer:

```
For Each c In Worksheets(4).Columns("A").Cells
```

I use "Worksheets(4)" because the table is in worksheet 4.

Comment: nice solution, but i might add, that this is most useful for small scale problems. If there should be anyone who uses this and is wondering about "why is it so slow" -> because you are using cells. If you need faster solutions you'll have to use arrays or other tricky ways ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the cells of any column in a table without needing the number of rows. If the table is in sheet1 of the workbook:

```
Dim rngCol as Range
Dim cl as Range
Set rngCol = Sheet1.Range("TableName[ColumnName]")
For Each cl in rngCol
    perform match of some type
Next cl
```

The code above will loop through the data values only, excluding the header row and the totals row. It is not necessary to specify the number of rows in the table.